# zip_entry_read return BOM charecter PHP

Tags: php, zip

i use zip_entry_read function to read 500 byte srt file in zip file but return BOM charecter, how i can fix that ?

```
$contents   = zip_entry_read($entry, 500);
```

**return :** G�� ��2 .H(� /1 'E'F F�3*